# How to always open vscode on macOS Big Sur with all windows maximized?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

I usually have 3-4 windows of vscode opened. Every time I reopen vscode on my macOS Big Sur laptop, only one of my windows gets fullscreened, others stay small and unmaximized.
I have these settings set, but it didn't help.

```
"window.restoreFullscreen": true,
"window.newWindowDimensions": "maximized",
"workbench.editor.restoreViewState": true
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get them all maximized? Be clear.

Comment: How to always open vs code on macOS Big Sur with all windows maximized

Comment: Did you found a way?